# How to click item in a listview using a custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to use a switch case statement on the clicked item in a custom listview but I'm unable to store that data value I click on and I can't store the item position to use it for my case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ListView listItemView;

 // Define string array.
 String[] listItemsValue = new String[] {"Android","PHP","Web Development","Blogger","SEO","Photoshop"};

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 listItemView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, listItemsValue);

 listItemView.setAdapter(adapter); 

 // ListView setOnItemClickListener function apply here.

 listItemView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
 {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
 int position, long id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, listItemsValue[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 });

 }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `OnItemClickListener` callback:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
       String value = list.getSelectedItem(); 
   }
}
```